# loop through array with 2 comma separated values, compare the two and record result

Tags: vb.net

I have an array of values

```
Dim result() As String = Split(values, ",")
```

the data in 'values' looks like this:

```
1576, 1589
1567, 1564
1555, 1570
1562, 1521
```

what i want to do is loop through the array, one line at a time and compare the values

```
if v1 (eg 1576) <= v2 (eg 1589) then record the number 1 in a separate variable, else 0
```

the resulting variable, with the recorded results will then look like this:

```
1
0
1
0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably want to store each pair of values in the array as a single string, so for instance (pseudo-code):

```
dim dataArray as new List(Of String)

for each line as string in InputFile
    dataArray.add(line)
Next

for each pair as string in dataArray
    dim v1, v2 as integer
    v1 = pair.Split(",")(0)
    v2 = pair.Split(",")(1)

    if v1 <= v2 then
        Console.WriteLine("1")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("0")
    EndIf
Next
```

That's assuming you're reading those values from some sort of file.  If you are,  you might as well just do the comparison as you read them in.  Anyway, that's a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: i like this code, but my data is not in a file, but contained in a variable, 'values', with two comma separated values per line. input file wont work. how do i reference my 'values' variable? thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use LINQ to do that:

```
Dim result() As String = (From i In values _
                          Let split = i.Split(",") _
                          Select If(Integer.Parse(split(0).Trim()) < Integer.Parse(split(1).Trim()), "1", "0")).ToArray()
```

Comment: Not a fan of the query comprehension syntax. I'd prefer to just use the extension methods... but that's a presonal preference, and this is otherwise dead on. +1

Comment: i like the concept here but i am getting an error "'Split' is not a member of 'Char'." how do i fix that error

Comment: btw the error shows up here, "Let split = i.Split(",")" -- with the blue error line (MS VS 2010) under the word 'Split'

Comment: From your first comment, it makes it look like `values` is an array of char, instead of an array of strings.  

Is this your code or a homework problem?  Doing something as an array of `char` seems odd, unless it's to make a homework question a bit more interesting.

If that is the case, that makes things a bit more difficult.  from your response to my answer above, you say the data is "contained in a variable, 'values', with two comma separated values per line".  do you mean that each string value in the array is a string of two comma seperated values?